# Small indexed tables - slow query postgres

Tags: postgresql

Running a dead simple query that is running quite slow on small indexed tables.

the query is:

```
select *
from rides as r
inner join vehicles as v
on v.vehicle_id = r.vehicle_id
```

vehicle_id on both tables is indexed,
rides has 30,000 rows, vehicle has 4 (Nothing massive here)

Query time was 1.5 minutes +

I then used Analyse on both rides and vehicles to bring the query time down to 47 seconds.

Initially running explain, it was using a hash match, after running analyse it now uses a merge join (a step in the right direction).

Still unsure as to why such small tables are taking so long to join.  I'm using AWS, I'm querying a replica of production, neither production or the replica are under any stress, the monitoring page all looks fine.  The lock manager shows no locks getting held.  What else can I do to troubleshoot??

I can join the users table to rides (which is significantly larger than the vehicles table) and it comes back sub 1 second.  The only problem with that is the user id isn't actually indexed and it is coming back faster than an indexed column :S

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
The column that we have the index on, also contains nulls, now I have been reading that this may effect performance?
I've just taken a copy of the tables and joined them together, performance without an index is the same as with an index which tells me that the index really isn't doing anything in this case.

**UPDATE 2:**
Query plan

```
Merge Join  (cost=0.42..1277.38 rows=33678 width=2234)
Merge Cond: (r2."vehicleId" = v.id)
->  Index Scan using rides_vehicle_id on rides r2  (cost=0.29..12089.11     rows=33678 width=1038)
 ->  Index Scan using vehicles_pkey on vehicles v  (cost=0.14..12.27 rows=9    width=1196)
```

**UPDATE 3: explain (analyze, buffers)**

```
    Merge Join  (cost=0.42..1279.26 rows=33709 width=2243) (actual time=0.024..5.656 rows=3441 loops=1)
    Merge Cond: (rides."vehicleId" = v.id)
    Buffers: shared hit=2912
    ->  Index Scan using rides_vehicle_id on rides  (cost=0.29..12074.77 rows=33709 width=1047) (actual time=0.014..2.357 rows=3442 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=2910
    ->  Index Scan using vehicles_pkey on vehicles v  (cost=0.14..12.27 rows=9 width=1196) (actual time=0.004..0.013 rows=9 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=2
  Planning time: 0.267 ms
  Execution time: 6.749 ms
```

**Update 4**

```
    CREATE TABLE public.rides (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    status enum_rides_status NOT NULL DEFAULT 'requested'::enum_rides_status,
    "departureTime" timestamptz NULL,
    "arrivalTime" timestamptz NULL,
    route jsonb NULL,
    "passengerCount" int4 NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "mergedId" int4 NULL,
    "ownerId" int4 NOT NULL,
    "createdAt" timestamptz NOT NULL,
    "updatedAt" timestamptz NOT NULL,
    "deletedAt" timestamptz NULL,
    "vehicleId" int4 NULL,
    "maxPassengerNumber" int4 NULL,
    "carOptional" bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    meta jsonb NULL,
    "networkId" int4 NULL,
    "pointType" enum_rides_pointType NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ALL_FIXED'::"enum_rides_pointType",
    "match" jsonb NULL,
    "passengerSeats" jsonb NULL,
    "seatingCapacity" jsonb NULL,
    events jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb,
    refid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "matchId" uuid NULL,
    "linkingUrl" varchar(255) NULL,
    "matcherVersion" int4 NULL,
    "createdBy" uuid NULL,
    "pickUpTimeWindowOffset" int4 NULL,
    "dropOffTimeWindowOffset" int4 NULL,
    "subStatus" enum_rides_subStatus NULL,
    "carparkPermitId" uuid NULL,
    CONSTRAINT rides_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT rides_refid_uk UNIQUE (refid)
 );
 CREATE INDEX "rides_id_deletedAt_status_departureTime_arrivalTime_idx" ON   public.rides USING btree (id, "deletedAt", status, "departureTime",  "arrivalTime");
 CREATE INDEX rides_network_id ON public.rides USING btree ("networkId");
 CREATE INDEX rides_vehicle_id ON public.rides USING btree ("vehicleId");

 ALTER TABLE public.rides ADD CONSTRAINT "rides_carparkPermitId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("carparkPermitId") REFERENCES carpark_permits(id);
 ALTER TABLE public.rides ADD CONSTRAINT "rides_createdBy_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("createdBy") REFERENCES ops_user(id);
 ALTER TABLE public.rides ADD CONSTRAINT "rides_matchId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("matchId") REFERENCES matches(refid);
 ALTER TABLE public.rides ADD CONSTRAINT "rides_networkId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("networkId") REFERENCES networks(id);
 ALTER TABLE public.rides ADD CONSTRAINT "rides_vehicleId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("vehicleId") REFERENCES vehicles(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Comment: Posting the result of EXPLAIN would likely help to give you a more qualified answer...

Comment: Your problem is indeed puzzling - 47 seconds to join two such tables strikes me as excessive. Can you post the structures of both tables (DDL - formatted text) please?

Comment: You mentioned this is on AWS. Do you mean an EC2 instances with postgres installed or and RDS instance of postgres? If it's EC2, have you made any changes to postgresql.conf and what are the hardware specs of the instance?

Comment: Just updated my initial question with the query plan above.  Also it is an RDS not an EC2

Comment: Unfortunately that's the output of a simple explain, not the output of **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**

Comment: Added explain (analyze, buffers)

Comment: how long "select * from rides" takes to complete? could you please add tables and indexes create statements?

Comment: select * from rides = 15 seconds for full table of 34,000 rows

Comment: Just added the table structure

Comment: please add vehicles table structure too

Comment: also please check how long does this query work: select 1
from rides as r
inner join vehicles as v
on v.vehicle_id = r.vehicle_id

Comment: the select 1 query comes back immediately with 34,000 rows